# "cert.rsa" file can not be found in the android APK

Tags: android, certificate, apk, rsa, meta-inf

I want to check the certificate used in the android APK file,so I used the follow command to print the info of certificate:

```
 unzip -p name-app.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert
```

But,it said "filename not matched:  META-INF/CERT.RSA".
Hence,I check the file list in the APK file using the command as follow:

```
unzip -l name-app.apk| grep META-INF
```

It just showed three files in the folder 'META-INF':

- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
- META-INF/WHATSAPP.SF
- META-INF/WHATSAPP.DSA or FILEEXPE.RSA

I cannot find out where the shoe pinches though i tried my best to search it online. So,my question are as follows:
1) if WHATSAPP.DSA is a replace of  CERT.RSA
2) what does FILEEXPE.RSA describe?

Can someone shed light on this problem for me?
Thanks in advance!